# Determine transitions and durations across rows in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "x1": [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    "x2": [3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3],
    "x3": [3, 2, 2, 3, 2, nan],
    "x4": [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, nan],
    "x5": [3, 2, 3, 2, 2, nan],
    "x6": [2, 1, nan, 2, 2, nan],
    "x7": [2, 2, nan, 2, 2, nan]
})
```

Each row represents an id and each column a state for a given month. For the sake of simplicity, you can assume that each id starts in state 3 and can change its state each month, either to 1, 2 or nan (which means the id is deleted).

For each id, I want to determine which ids change their states directly from 3 to 2 and how long they remain in 2.

Expected result:

```py
out = pd.Series([2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0])
```

I want to achieve this result in pure pandas and beat my solution in terms of code complexity and time.

My solution so far:

```py
import numba

@numba.njit
def _get_duration(l):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        cond = l[i-1] == 3
        # If state remains in 3, just continue
        if cond and l[i] == 3:
            continue
        # If state changes from 3 to 2 set counter
        elif cond and l[i] == 2:
            counter = 1
        # If state remains in 2, increase counter
        elif l[i-1] == 2 and l[i] == 2:
            counter +=1
        else:
            break
    return counter


@numba.njit
def get_stage2_duration(stg):
    N = stg.shape[0]
    return [_get_duration(stg[i]) for i in range(N)]
```

Yields the following result:

```py
get_stage2_duration(df.values) # [2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using masks.

Starting with the case in which we would count all 2s that follow a 3:

```
is2 = df.eq(2)
was3 = df.mask(is2).ffill(axis=1).eq(3)
out = (is2 & was3).sum(axis=1)
# [2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 0]
```

Intermediate `out` before summing (`True` is `■`, `False` is `□`):

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
0  □  □  □  □  □  ■  ■
1  □  □  ■  ■  ■  □  □
2  □  ■  ■  □  □  □  □
3  □  ■  □  ■  ■  ■  ■
4  □  □  □  □  ■  ■  ■
5  □  □  □  □  □  □  □
```

Now, if we only want the first stretch of 2s, let's mask the others

```
was2 = df.shift(axis=1).eq(2)
(is2 & was3).mask((was2 & ~is2).cummax(axis=1)).sum(axis=1)
# [2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

Intermediate `out` before summing (no character is `NaN`):

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
0  □  □  □  □  □  ■  ■
1  □  □  ■  ■  ■      
2  □  ■  ■            
3  □  ■               
4  □  □  □            
5  □  □  □  □  □  □  □
```

##### alternative

```
# is the value a 2?
is2 = df.eq(2)
# is the immediate preceding value a 2?
was2 = is2.shift(axis=1, fill_value=False)
# was the previous non-2 a 3?
was3 = df.mask(is2).ffill(axis=1).eq(3)
# combine conditions
out = ((was3 & is2) & ~(was2 & ~is2).cummax(axis=1)).sum(axis=1)
# [2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

Intermediate `out` before summing:

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
0  □  □  □  □  □  ■  ■
1  □  □  ■  ■  ■  □  □
2  □  ■  ■  □  □  □  □
3  □  ■  □  □  □  □  □
4  □  □  □  □  □  □  □
5  □  □  □  □  □  □  □
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

`df`

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7
0   3   3   3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0
1   3   3   2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 2.0
2   3   2   2.0 1.0 3.0 NaN NaN
3   3   2   3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
4   3   1   2.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
5   3   3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

**Step1**

convert to NaN all first 3 streak

```
df1 = df[(df.ne(3) & df.shift(1, axis=1).eq(3)).cumsum(axis=1).ge(1)]
```

`df1`

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.0 2.0
1   NaN NaN 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 2.0
2   NaN 2.0 2.0 1.0 3.0 NaN NaN
3   NaN 2.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
4   NaN 1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

**Step2**

Find the part of df1 that is not (NaN or 2).

Change all occurrences after the first occurrence to NaN

```
df2 = df1[(~(df1.eq(2) | df1.isna())).cumsum(axis=1).lt(1)]
```

`df2`

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.0 2.0
1   NaN NaN 2.0 2.0 2.0 NaN NaN
2   NaN 2.0 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

**Final**

count non-null by row

```
df2.count(axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    2
1    3
2    2
3    1
4    0
5    0
```

**Full Code**

df2 is made for better understanding, and the full code is as follows

```
df1 = df[(df.ne(3) & df.shift(1, axis=1).eq(3)).cumsum(axis=1).ge(1)]
df1[(~(df1.eq(2) | df1.isna())).cumsum(axis=1).lt(1)].count(axis=1)
```